# Android NDK: Using libtool library

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, automake, libtool

The following library is created with autotools:

Makefile.am:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libandi.la
libandi_la_SOURCES = $(SMILE_SOURCES)
libandi_la_CPPFLAGS = $(SMILE_CPPFLAGS)
libandi_la_LIBADD = $(SMILE_LIBS)
libandi_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////This will be gone since I want to use libandi in android project
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bin_PROGRAMS = AndiExtract
AndiExtract_SOURCES = src/AndiExtract.cpp 
AndiExtract_CPPFLAGS = $(Andi_CPPFLAGS)
AndiExtract_LDADD = $(Andi_LIBS) -libandi -->I need this linker in android
//////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I can compile it with android ndk so thats not the problem.

But **how can I link to the libtool library libandi.la**? In the android.mk file? Is it even possible? I couldn't find the answer when searching online.  Thanks.

Comment: Almost 10 years and i still have the same question and it is still ununswered. All the GNU software now sucks.